# Task succeeds but the service onSucceed method is not triggered

Tags: java, javafx, task

When the Task includes 2 lines opening a stream and closing it, the Task returns correctly. Its `succeed` method runs. **But the Service' `setOnSucceeded` method does not run.** Why?

When the 2 lines about the streaming opening and closing are commented out in the Task, we do get the expected behavior:  `System.out.println("in the succeed method of the Service")` does print.

The Main method:

```
package Test;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        MyService pluginUpdateService = new MyService();
        pluginUpdateService.setOnFailed(e -> {
            System.out.println("task failed");
        });
        pluginUpdateService.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
            System.out.println("in the succeed method of the Service"); // this does not print, when MyTask opens the stream (see code of MyTask)
        });
        // launching the service
        if (pluginUpdateService.getState() == Worker.State.READY) {
            pluginUpdateService.start();
        }
    }
}
```

The service `MyService`

```
package Test;

import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

public class MyService extends Service {

    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    protected Task createTask() {
        Task updater = new MyTask();
        return updater;
    }
}
```

The task `MyTask`:

```
package Test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;


public class MyTask extends Task {


    public MyTask() {

    }

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        InputStream in;
            URL url = new URL("https://clementlevallois.net");
            in = url.openStream(); // when this line is commented out, the Service does trigger its setOnSucceeded method as expected
            in.close(); // when this line is commented out, the Service does trigger its setOnSucceeded method as expected
        System.out.println("about to return from the call method of the Task");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void succeeded() {
        super.succeeded();
        System.out.println("succeeded - sent from the succeeded method of the Task");
    }

    @Override
    protected void cancelled() {
        super.cancelled();
        System.out.println("cancelled");
        updateMessage("Cancelled!");
    }

    @Override
    protected void failed() {
        super.failed();
        System.out.println("failed");
        updateMessage("Failed!");
    }

}
```

Comment: Create a [mre].

Comment: I edited the question, this is my minimum reproducible example

Comment: That's not a [mre]. Can you create something we can copy, paste, and run? If it's not triggering `onSucceeded` or `onFailed`, the reasonable conclusion should be that it's not exiting. But unless other people can test, we can't really help.

Comment: did further edits to provide an MRE.

Comment: Thanks. I can reproduce that. I'm not sure what's going on, but somehow the URL connection is preventing the thread running the task from exiting. (If you create your own thread to run the task, and don't use a service, you can see that the thread doesn't exit.)